# How to set JtextArea to keep fixed no of rows?

Tags: java, jtextarea

How can i keep no of rows constant in text area.
I need to create a console window for my application.
If rows exceeds predefined no of rows first rows must get disposed. 
As if first written row will be destroyed first when i append anything which exceeds no of rows set.
One more thing , i need to keep vertical scroll bar. That means no of rows must not be the whatever rows are visible when text area it opened.

For example : - no of visible rows on view port are 30. 
It should keep 120 rows information, which will can be seen with the help of scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want to do is create your own Document implementation. See [Document](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html).

Answer (score 0):

The [Message Console](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) shows one way.